# Is there a service which will let me create a snippet of a webpage

Tags: code-snippets

I am looking for a way to get the essence or the most important aspect of a webpage? If I provide a URL, is there any external service which can accomplish this? I am not looking for snap.com like service as it provides a snapshot.

I might be willing to even implement such a system on my own. For beginning I do not want to put excessive effort, but rather would love to able to get some basic results. Are there any thoughts on how I may approach this problem?

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you mean by "most important aspect of a page". 

An alternative to snap.com is http://browsershots.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Yahoo's Term extraction service](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/content/V2/termExtraction.html)

**Update 02-May-2012**

Yahoo has release a new [Content Analysis Web service](http://developer.yahoo.com/contentanalysis/) which will be replacing the Term extraction service. It can be invoked by syntactically sweet YQL as shown below

```
select * from contentanalysis.analyze where url='http://www.cnn.com/2011/11/11/world/europe/greece-main/index.html';
```

There is also [AlchemyAPI](http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/demo.html) which offers a weservice which may serve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

By snippet, do you mean like a quote that sums up the entire page you want to link to?

So if snap.com isn't a fancy, what about the entire page? For verbosity's sake? You could try out [BackupURL](http://www.backupurl.com/) if you want like a cache of the entire page of the site instead just a snapshot of a portion of it.